# Copy row to new sheet using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I know it has been asked and answered here many times, but I can not make it work. I am trying to copy a row values (no formulas) from one sheet to another sheet on googlesheets using Google Apps Script. Very basic, but somehow it is giving me hard time.

I have:
SourceSheet
SourceWorksheet
TargetSheet
TargetWorksheet

I am trying to Copy row values (no formulas) from SourceWorksheet(A2:K2), to a new row (after last used row) on TargetWorksheet. It will be again from (A:K) but row number will be different, each time it will create a new row after last row.

Any help would be really appreciated!

**EDIT**
I found this code below, but not sure how to modify it to read the range i mentioned above instead of all the rows from source worksheet, and I need to modify it so it finds last row on target worksheet then creates new row each time to write the values ( so it doesn't overwrite any data on target)

```
function myFunction() {
var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxx');
var sourcesheet = source.getSheetByName('sheet1');
var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxx')
var targetsheet = target.getSheetByName('sheet1');
var targetrange = targetsheet.getRange(2, 1, sourcesheet.getLastRow(), sourcesheet.getLastColumn());
var rangeValues = sourcesheet.getRange(2, 1, sourcesheet.getLastRow(), sourcesheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
targetrange.setValues(rangeValues); 
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have already tried? Please check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with help on how to create an example.

Comment: We don't know what you know or don't know.  Someone would need to start from the beginning and explain everything, or just write the entire code for you.  Can you get a script to write *anything* to a spreadsheet?  Anything at all?  Are you looking in the Execution Transcript for errors and what line they occurred on?  Have you read the [Link to Troubleshooting](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. how to write a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys! Sorry not use to post question here. I now added the script I found above in my question. Don't know how to modify it tho. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

To add a line to the last row of a form, use the `sheet.appendRow()` method.

In your example, `var targetRange` would not be needed. You could simply use `targetSheet.appendRow(rangeValues)` where the rangeValues = the range you're copying (as an array)

```
function myFunction() {
var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxx');
var sourcesheet = source.getSheetByName('sheet1');
var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxx')
var targetsheet = target.getSheetByName('sheet1');
var rangeValues = sourcesheet.getRange(2, 1, sourcesheet.getLastRow(), sourcesheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
targetSheet.appendRow(rangeValues); 
}
```